# Is it possible to create a file that is used along side autorun, to automatically enter a password via flash drive?

Tags: autorun

I am wondering if there is code or something that can be used along side autorun in order to enter a password automatically. For example, I am the system administrator and some people have secretly used a key logger to get the administrative password. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically enter the password into the User Account Password Box, without actually typing out the password, using a flash drive, autorun, and the special file.

Comment: You're probably looking for a smart card.

Comment: I was hoping to use like a batch file or a script of some sort that i could run automatically with an autorun file on a flash drive.